# DATE_SUB over an extracted month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In postgres, one can do the following:

```
date_trunc('Month',event_date) AS obs_date,
prev.obs_date = curr.obs_date - INTERVAL '1 MONTH'
```

I am trying to do the same thing on bigquery using DATE_SUB:

```
WITH monthly_user_counts AS (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(MONTH from PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',event_date)) AS obs_date,
    user_pseudo_id
  FROM
    `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
),
returning_users AS (
  SELECT
    curr.obs_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT prev.user_pseudo_id) AS returning_user_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT curr.user_pseudo_id) AS total_users
  FROM
    monthly_user_counts curr
  LEFT JOIN
    monthly_user_counts prev
  ON
    curr.user_pseudo_id = prev.user_pseudo_id AND prev.obs_date =  DATE_SUB(curr.obs_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  GROUP BY
    curr.obs_date
),
inter AS (
  SELECT
    obs_date,
    returning_user_count,
    total_users,
    (returning_user_count * 100.0 / total_users) AS monthly_return_percentage
  FROM
    returning_users
  ORDER BY
    obs_date
)

SELECT * FROM inter;
```

This gives the following error:

```
No matching signature for function DATE_SUB for argument types: INT64, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signatures: DATE_SUB(DATE, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_SUB(DATETIME, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_SUB(TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART) at [18:68]
```

Am I using DATE_SUB incorrectly in this context? Here is what ChatGPT says: As of my last update in September 2021, Google BigQuery does not have a direct DATE_SUB function that works with intervals like in PostgreSQL.

Comment: ...did you try to read the documentation, instead of just relying on ChatGPT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as curr.obs_date is an int32 and not a date, you can not use Date functions on it

Simple arithmetic suffice

```
prev.obs_date = curr.obs_date -1
```